# How to get value from customer's notes field?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am working on shopify and my requirement is to add some extra information of user and I did that following this link :-

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/communicating-with-customers/accounts-and-newsletters/capture-additional-information-in-the-account-registration-form

But now I want to know how to get values from customer[note][label] field in my liquid code.
Like I am able to get customer's name using `{{customer.name}}` which is store in customer[name] field but unable to get values from **customer[note][label]** field.

Answer (score 8):

`customer.note` is not exposed via the the [`customer` Liquid object](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/customer). It is currently only available via the [Shopify API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer). This is because customer notes are not meant for displaying in your store, they are for shop owners to manage customers in the admin area. An alternative is to use [metafields](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/metafield) instead.

Relevant discussions on the Shopify forums:

- [Accessing Customer Note in Account.liquid template](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/accessing-customer-note-in-account-liquid-template-145742)
- [how to access to the customer.note with Liquid](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-access-to-the-customer-note-with-liquid-186535)

Comment: Hey thanku but can you please guide how to use metafields in my customer registration's form so to store some additional information.
My requirement is basically that after sign up that account must be approved by admin in order to access that account next time.

Comment: @user3496835 You could use one of the apps listed [here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/metafield), e.g. [Metafields2](https://apps.shopify.com/metafields2). If all you need to do is mark a customer as approved, perhaps [tags](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/customer#customer-tags) are all you need. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15461565/1367622) of how to add tags to a customer.

Comment: @user3496835 You can access [`customer.tags`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/customer#customer-tags) via Liquid, unlike `customer.note`.

Comment: Here's an example with GraphQL Admin API https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/retrieving-the-customer-note/m-p/2021774/highlight/true#M124537